# Pointwise limit of measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit of measures is again a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118592/limit-of-measures-is-again-a-measure)

If $$ P(A) = \lim_n P_n(A)$$ for every $A \in$ $\sigma-$field $\mathcal{F}$. Can we prove that if $P_n$ are probability measures then $P$ is also a probability measure, using Steinhaus's lemma?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118592/limit-of-measures-is-again-a-measure

Comment: And what do you mean by "Steinhaus's lemma"? The only result I know by this name is for a more specialized setting.

Comment: problem 7 section 1.5 Robert Ash. (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC)

Comment: and yes  the above post's answer uses it.