# "pointwise convergence"of measures

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega , \mathcal{A})$ be any measurable space, and let $(\mu_n)_n$ be a sequence of probability measures on this space, such that the limit $\mu(A) = \lim \mu_n(A)$ exists for any $A \in  \mathcal{A}$.

Then $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure of total mass $1$ on $(\Omega , \mathcal{A})$. Is it always true that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive?

Comment: This is the Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem

Comment: Thanks ! (and this is definitely an answer rather than a comment )

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118592/limit-of-measures-is-again-a-measure