# Extracting a subsequence from a sequence of $\mathcal{L}^1$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

Any help with the following problem is appreciated.

**Given:** a sequence of nonnegative functions $(g_n)$ which are U.I. ([uniformly integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability)) in $\mathcal{L}^1(0,1)$ with $\sup_n \Vert g_n \Vert_1 < \infty$.

**Claim:** there exist $ g \in \mathcal{L}^1(0,1)$ and a subsequence $(g_{n_k})$ such that 
$$\forall \, \text{ measurable }E \subset [0,1]\qquad \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_E g_{n_k} =\int_E g .$$

I am having difficulty proving the claim.

Comment: @julien - Yes, uniform integrability, it is

Comment: Then I've added the information, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: sounds like an extension of bolzano weierstrass

Comment: That's fine @julien

Comment: This fact (with $(0,1)$ replaced by a general measure space) is called the Dunford-Pettis theorem (one of several results by that name).  [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#cite_note-2) you can find a proof in Dellacherie and Mayer; I believe it is also in Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sketch I would follow.

1. Consider the measures $\nu_n$ defined by $\nu_n(E) = \int_E g_n\,dm$.  This is a bounded sequence of positive measures, so by Helly's selection theorem (or Banach-Alaoglu or something analogous) we can extract a subsequence $\nu_{n_k}$ converging vaguely to some measure $\nu$, i.e. $\int h g_n\,dm \to \int h\,d\nu$ for every $h \in C_c((0,1))$.
2. Use the uniform integrability to show that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous to $m$ (the characterization of uniform integrability in terms of uniform absolute continuity would be helpful) and hence by Radon-Nikodym is of the form $\nu(E) = \int g \,dm$ for some $g$.
3. For a compact set $K$, approximate $1_K$ by continuous compactly supported functions to conclude that $\int_K g_n\,dm \to \int_K g\,dm$.
4. Consider the set $\mathcal{L}$ of all measurable sets $E$ for which $\int_E g_n\,dm \to \int g\,dm$.  Use a monotone class argument to show that $\mathcal{L}$ consists of all measurable sets.

If you use this for a homework problem, please credit me (and give the URL of this answer) in your submission.

Comment: Is this a correct approach: 
1. Prove the sequence, $G_n(x) = \int_0^x g_n(t) dt $ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ is uniform absolute continuous. 
2. Apply uniform boundedness principle to prove $G_n$ is uniformly bounded.
3. Use Diagonal argument to extract subsequence that converges for all rationals in $[0,1]$.
4. (3) $\Rightarrow$ Convergence is for all $x \in [0,1]$ and infact uniform

Comment: @pondy: Sure, in fact that's one way to prove Helly's selection theorem which I mention in step 1.

Comment: The argument does prove existence and convergence to an absolute continuous function $\int g$. Can I then do the following $\vert \int_E (g_{n_k}-g) \vert \leq \int (g_{n_k} - g) \rightarrow 0$ for large enough $n_k$ for any measurable subset $E$ of $[0,1]$, to prove the claim

Comment: I solved the problem using Arzela-Ascoli. I was dumb not to see that before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $\{E_j,j\in\Bbb N\}$ be an algebra generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the unit interval. By boundedness, we can find a nested sequence of infinite subsets of the set of natural numbers $(I_j,j\in\Bbb N)$ such that $\left(\int_{E_j}h_nd\lambda,n\in I_j\right)$ is convergent.
2. By a diagonal argument, we can find a subsequence $(h_{n_k},k\in\Bbb N)$ such that for each $j$, the sequence $\left(\int_{E_j}h_{n_k}d\lambda,k\in \Bbb N\right)$ is Cauchy.
3. By [an approximation argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra) and the assumption of uniform integrability, we can show that for each $E\subset [0,1]$ measurable, the sequence $\left(\int_Eh_{n_k}d\lambda,k\in\Bbb N\right)$ is convergent.
4. Let $\mu_k(E):=\int_Eh_{n_k}d\lambda$. Then $\mu_k$ is a finite measure. By 3. and [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118592/limit-of-measures-is-again-a-measure?rq=1), the map $\mu\colon E\mapsto \lim_{k\to +\infty}\mu_k(E)$ is a measure. By boundedness in $L^1$, this is a finite measure. Furthermore, $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Radon-Nykodym theorem gives $g$.

Comment: Is this a correct approach: 1. Prove the sequence, $G_n(x)=\int_0^x g_n(t)dt$ for $0\le x \le 1$ is uniform absolute continuous. 2. Apply uniform boundedness principle to prove $(G_n)$ is uniformly bounded. 3. Use Diagonal argument to extract subsequence that converges for all rationals in $[0,1]$. 4. (3) $\Rightarrow$ Convergence is for all $x \in [0,1]$ and in fact uniform

Comment: This will give you that the limit exists for a sub-sequence for any interval. It's a step to the result, but as it stands it's not enough.

Comment: What is it that is missing?

Comment: We need the property to be true for all the measurable subsets of $[0,1]$, not only intervals. And how do you show the existence of $g$?

Comment: (3) $\Rightarrow$ the subsequence converges and that $\int g$ is also absolutely continuous.